# Delphi XE . How to dynamic change label text from a resource file?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, multiplatform

i have a resource file contain bunch of predefined words from difference country and i have to change label text when user select button english or japan...etc. Is there any way to do this?. Thanks

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with?

Comment: Thanks guys i found out the instruction, my bad in googling.
But i'm struggling with  | Update Localized Projects part. In my XE 8, The Language part unable to click in it and i can see my button1 anywhere in RC file.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi, can you provide me some information about instantly change language when i'm click button in multiplatform apps(android and ios) ? I'm struggling with it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I think you need to work on that.